# When to use pygame.sprite.GroupSingle?

Tags: sprites, pygame

I'm doing a game in which i have a ball which is controlled by the keyboard and the goal is to get is out of a maze without touching the walls.

I've added my ball sprite to `GroupSprite`

```
vehicle = pygame.sprite.GroupSingle(Vehicle(70,470))
```

since at the time, i thought that was the right way of doing it. However, i found that all the interaction always goes with the sprite directlly not with the `GroupSingle`. So I end with constantly accessing the sprite throug the `GroupSingle.sprite`:

```
vehicle.sprite.desired_speed_up_down
```

Is there a reason why i shouldn't just remove 'GroupSingle' and define:

```
vehicle = Vehicle(70,470)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If you don't use any features of the `Group`, you can just stop using it.

---

However, nothing is stoping you from storing your player `Sprite` in a seperate field and using your `GroupSingle` for stuff like collision detection/drawing/updating if you maintain a list of `SpriteGroup`s for example to have your code look more uniformly:

```
# initialize
vehicle = Vehicle(70,470)

vehicle_group     = pygame.sprite.GroupSingle(vehicle) # make it clear there's only one vehicle (player) by using GroupSingle
wall_group        = pygame.sprite.Group(YourWallSpritesOrSomething)
other_stuff_group = pygame.sprite.Group(OtherStuffSprites)
all_groups        = (vehicle_group, wall_group, other_stuff_group)
...

# drawing eveything, including player, walls, and stuff...
for g in all_groups:
    g.draw(screen)
...

# updating eveything, including player, walls, and stuff...
for g in all_groups:
    g.update(...)

# test if 'somesprite' collides with anything, including player:
if any(spritecollideany(somesprite, g) for g in all_groups):
    do_stuff(somesprite)

# test if player (vehicle) hits a wall:
if spritecollideany(vehicle, wall_group):
    lose_game()
```

But if the `Sprite` in your `GroupSingle` never changes, a regular `Group` would also be fine, but a `GroupSingle` would nonetheless make the fact clearer that there's *always a single* vehicle.